# Flutter command unfound

Tags: flutter, cmd

I recently downloaded Flutter, I read the installation documentation and have everything they say. But I still have a major problem, when I open my cmd and type `flutter` my cmd don't find it. I set up the bin path is my Path local variable but still don't work. The path is correct, everything is ok but can't work.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you entered in your PATH variable?

Comment: are you working on windows, mac, or linux?

Comment: Yes i added it to my PATH variable and I’m on Windows

Comment: Please start by opening a Command Prompt window, typing `path`, pressing the `[ENTER]` key and then [edit]ing your question to include the output within a code box. _You can do that by copying the content of the cmd.exe window, and pasting it into your question body, then highlighting it, and pressing on the **`{}`** button_.